# События с мышью

Tags: jquery, события

На сайте есть блок:

```
<div id="is">
<a href="#">Показать блок</a>
 <span id="box" style="display: none">
  <a href="#">ссылка</a>
  <a href="#">ссылка</a>
  <a href="#">ссылка</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

задача в том, что если навести мышью (курсор) на блок с айди "is" то появляется блок с ссылками (id="box") и для этого написал код jQuery:

```
$("#is").mouseover(function(){ 
$('#box').show('slow');
}).mouseout(function() {
$('#box').hide('slow');
});
```

Скрипт работает, но при каждой наведении на ссылок которые находятся в **id="box"** - этот блок моргает, то появляется то исчезает. 
Как правильно сделать, чтобы скрипт работал по идеи, если навести на **div id=is"** то появляется блок **id="box"** и когда убрать курсор с блока **id="is"** блок **id="box"** исчезает..?

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это проще на css сделать:

```
#is #box {
    display: none;
}
#is:hover #box {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/vzenW/

а вот на js:

JS:

```
var box = $('#box');
var is = $('#is');
$('#is a').mouseover(box_show);
$(is).mouseout(box_hide);

function box_show() {
    box.show('slow');

}

function box_hide(e) {
    if (is.css('cursor')=='text') return;
    box.stop();
    box.hide('slow');
}
```

CSS:

```
#is #box {
    display: none;
}
#is:hover {
    cursor: text;
}
```

хитрость тут в том, чтобы выставлять какой-нибудь невидимый для пользователя атрибут css в заранее известный статус при  `:hover`, потом, при выходе из элемента, мы проверяем  `:hover` таким хитрым способом и ,если курсор все еще в блоке, то не прячем элемент.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/p6LX7/

ps: чтобы не дергался блок надо использовать `fadeOut('slow')`, вместо `hide('slow')`

Comment: Благодарю, за ваше внимание! Разобрался и понял все ошибки. Спасибо.